# Has Many Dependent Destroy Doesn't Destroy Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

**UPDATE**: It's possible that there is a gem that prevents this configuration. None of these gems look like the culprits but if anyone thinks they spot one please let me know. Thanks!

Working with Rails 3 here. I have two models.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invitations, dependent: :destroy
end

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

When I run the following..

```
contact = Contact.first // has associated invitations 

contact.destroy
```

The contact is destroyed but the invitation is not. When I look at the logs I see the following sql query printout..

```
  Invitation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `invitations`.* FROM `invitations` WHERE `invitations`.`contact_id` = 51
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  UPDATE `contacts` SET `deleted_at` = '2016-02-25 13:05:38', `updated_at` = '2016-02-25 13:05:38' WHERE `contacts`.`id` = 51
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
```

When I look into the database the invitation records still exists.

My gemfile...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.22.1'

# testing libraries
group :development, :test do
  # fixture replacement
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.4.1'
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.3.0'
  gem 'webrick', '~> 1.3.1'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.2'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.6.1'
  gem 'spork', '~> 1.0.0rc4'
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers', '~> 1.1.1'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails', '1.1.7'
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.6'
end

group :development do
  gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.3.5"
  gem "hpricot", ">= 0.8.6"
  gem "ruby_parser", ">= 3.0.1"
  gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.1"
  #gem "better_errors", ">= 2.1.1"
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.2.9', require: false
  gem 'letter_opener', '~> 1.2.0'
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'

gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.2.1'

# have to throw in this again, the server's sprocket will fail if this gem is missing
gem "bootstrap-sass-rails", ">= 2.3.2.1"
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.1.0.0'
gem 'google_visualr', '~> 2.5.1'

gem 'angularjs-rails', '~> 1.4.7'
gem 'ngannotate-rails', '~> 0.9.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
gem "haml", ">= 3.1.7"
gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.6.3.1"
gem 'slim-rails', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'


# Handles cron jobs
gem 'whenever', '~> 0.9.4'

gem "annotate", "~> 2.6.2"
gem 'oj', '~> 2.8.1'

gem "devise", "~> 3.0.3"
gem "cancan", ">= 1.6.8"
gem "rolify", ">= 3.2.0"
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.0.4"
gem 'chosen-rails', '~> 1.1.0'

gem 'formtastic', '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'jquery_datepicker', '~> 0.4'
gem 'bettertabs', '~> 1.4.1'
gem 'country_select', '~> 1.3.1'

gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.5'
gem 'capistrano-ext', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'rvm-capistrano', '~> 1.5.1', require: false

gem 'net-ssh', '2.7.0'

gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.8.0.218'

gem 'rack-cache', '~> 1.2', require: 'rack/cache'
gem 'dragonfly', '~>0.9.15'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-tooltip-rails', '~> 0.1'

gem 'omnicontacts', '~> 0.3.7'
gem 'roo', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'roo-xls', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.1.7'
gem "googlecharts", '~> 1.6.12', require: "gchart"
gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0.3"
gem 'rack-google_analytics', '~> 1.0.2'
gem 'rambling-slider-rails', '~> 0.2.0'
gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0'



#ecomm group from stripe
gem "figaro", ">= 0.6.3"
gem "stripe", '~> 1.17.1'
gem "stripe_event", '~> 1.4.0'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.7.2'
```

What is wrong with this code and how do I fix it?

Comment: What Gem are you using to soft delete or you are doing it manually? The reason your child records `invitations` are not destroyed, because the parent is not destroyed, it is just _archived_.

Comment: Which gem? Do you mean the rails version? I'm confused by your question.

Comment: He means, the contact record is not being deleted but instead its "deleted_at" field is being updated with a timestamp.  Since this is not being deleted on destroy, no associated records will be removed.  This is more than likely a gem or config option you changed from the standard rails library as I don't see a problem with your syntax.  The gem "Paranoia" does this so if you could add your gemfile that may help.

Comment: I'm not aware of any gems that would cause that.. I've attached my Gemfile to the question. Hopefully someone can spot it for me.

Comment: It is possible that someone may have reconfigured the way your destroy method works since you handle stripe transactions as per your gemfile.  Normally, financial records are marked as deleted and never removed for archiving purposes so that could be your issue right there.  Look at your db:schema and any tables that have a "deleted_at" field are probably going to be an issue for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think someone in your app may have overridden the way destroy works either through a method in the model or a gem.  Check for something along the lines like

```
  def destroy
    self.update_attributes(deleted_at: DateTime.current)
  end
```

If there's something like that you'll have to override it.  I'd start by looking at all tables in your db:schema with a "deleted_at" column and add a destroy method to those models using `super` to call the ActiveRecord::Base destroy method.

Comment: Yep. Just noticed this `destroy` method in my `Contact` model. Could I not just remove the method altogether? Obviously, I would have to check throughout my app on why the original developer used this method.

Comment: Yes you can remove it and it will be fine as long as you're certain the record is safe for removal.  The way ruby works, it just climbs up the inheritance tree looking for the method you called starting with the lowest level.  In this case, it found destroy attached to the model and didnt have to use the one higher up in the tree under ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: Then using `super` as well can be an alternate method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to paranoid gem it use for logical delete.You can delete from db by following code

```
 contact = Contact.first // has associated invitations 
 contact.really_destroy!
```

Visit https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia